Extract a value from JSON string
I'm trying to extract the value of tax_amount from JSON string but this line
let taxAmountS = json["tax_amount"] as? String

triggers an error.   A print out of json (json string) looks like it should work, here it is
["client_secret": pi_3Q5hYZHbqLi, "tax_amount": 192, "total": 2424]

It contains "tax_amount": 192.  Can anyone assist with how to extract the value of 192 from the json string?
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                //let taxAmountS = json["tax_amount"] as? String,
                let self = self else {
                    print("Error")
                return
            }
            
            print("json is ", json)
            
            taxAmt = (taxAmountS as NSString).doubleValue


tax amount is pretty clearly not a string but a number?

I don't know squat about swift but that looks like an array object to me, not a json object.

@chonerman It's Hashmap | Dictionary format in Swift such as: [Key: Value, Key: Value...]

I believe the value of the key tax_amount is a Number rather than a String. It should be:
let mock: [String: Any] = ["client_secret": "pi_3Q5hYZHbqLi", "tax_amount": 192, "total": 2424]

if let taxAmount = mock["tax_amount"] as? Int {
    print(taxAmount)
    //192
}


I strongly suggest to keep data type for tax_amount as Double. For sure it can be 24.25

Then it must be 192.0 or even a string "192.0", otherwise it will return false during decoding. @FahimParkar

192 as Double is fine too... It won't throw any exception while decoding & "192.0" will surely give error for decoding as Double...

please check your data types. The issue is because you are attempting to cast tax_amount as a String, but the value is actually a Number (specifically, an Int in your case).
You can maybe properly extract the value

Cast the Tax_amount to NSnumber, int, or maybe double

anyways the issue is the datatype and how you cast it.
probably..
